# Correct Apache2 AddType directives for caching fonts

Tags: apache-2.4, cache-control

I'm using apache 2 and have set caching directives as follows in the virtual servers conf file:

```
<FilesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|woff2)$"> Header set Cache-Control "ETag, public" </Filesmatch>
```

This seems to be working ok apart from caching the woff2 font, I've tried everything in the following thread: [Correct Apache AddType directives for font MIME types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415640/correct-apache-addtype-directives-for-font-mime-types/71118542#71118542)

Google Page Speed still reports the fonts as un-cached however. The directives in the quoted thread were added without removing woff2 from the ETag cache control if that would make any difference.

Site in question is: https://dmmblitz.com

Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `ETag` with `max-age=31536000` (for a user caching TTL = 1 year)

Comment: The ETag works fine with other file types, the issue is related to this rather than cache control?